# how to change my button color based on some condition? I want less in one color and more in another color

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'

const LessMoreData = ({data}) => {
    const [readMore , setReadMore] = useState(false);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                {readMore ? data : `${data.substring(0,100)}`}
                <button onClick = {() => setReadMore(!readMore)} 
                    style = {{backgroundColor: "black", color: "yellow"}}>
                    {readMore ? 'LESS' : 'MORE'}
                </button>
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default LessMoreData
```

Comment: Use a ternary like you did in `readMore ? 'LESS' : 'MORE'`?

Comment: style={{
            backgroundColor: readMore ? "black" : "yellow",
            color: "yellow"
          }}

Answer (score 0):

Use ClassName.

```
 className={readMore?'LESS':'MORE'}
```